# How to get the message for audio that browser is not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using html5 audio. I have defined the audio tag from the below link. when you open the below link in safari it will show the message browser is not supported and when you open the 
link in ie it is showing differently. I want the same message for ie also

http://jsfiddle.net/WMSsh/

I have defined the code in html as

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: The above is a duplicate - ignore the 'MP3' part of the title, it's poorly named.

Comment: _“Why ie doesn't display message like safari”_ – because IE (10) supports the `audio` element, but not the file types given – and that’s exactly what he’s saying …

Answer (score 0):

I think try Modernizr.js

```
if(Modernizr.audio){
   alert("Your browser supports audio tag, enjoy!!");
}else{
alert("Sorry, browser does not support audio tag!");
}
```

Comment: Why ie doesn't display message like safari